# Query table schema in SOQL

Tags: soql, query, schema

Is it possible to query the schema of a Salesforce table using SOQL?

The MySQL equivalent is;

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schema information isn't available via query, however there is an API for it. Depending on what type of development you're doing:

- [Apex methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm)
- [SOAP API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm)
- [REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_describe.htm)
- [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/customobject.htm)

They all work a bit differently so if you have specific questions about using one of them it might be best in a followup question.